# ggrepel: plot labels above points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I want to plot labels precisely above points where possible (no overlap), but ggrepel seems to insist on plotting slightly above or below.  E.g.

```
require(ggplot); require(ggrepel)

ggplot(iris[1:10,], aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(pch=1, size=8) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=Species), segment.color=NA, 
                  point.padding=unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]

You can of course reduce the `force` argument, but then labels don't repel each other when they *do* overlap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, you can avoid overlapping by giving `point.padding` the same value as `geom_point(size)`. And you can define above position by giving `nudge_y` a very small plus value.

```
library(dplyr)
 ## an example data (delete duplicated data)
iris2 <- iris %>% distinct(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, .keep_all = T)

g <- ggplot(iris2[1:20,], aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(pch=1, size=8)
g + geom_text_repel(aes(label=Species), segment.color=NA, 
                    point.padding = unit(8, "points"), nudge_y = 1.0E-6)
```

**[EDITED]**
I guess `box.padding = unit(-0.5, "lines")` gives the labels the points positions (but it probably bases on Capital letters).

```
iris2$Species <- as.character(iris2$Species)
iris2[7,5] <- "ABCDEFG"

g2 <- ggplot(iris2[1:20,], aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(pch = 1, size = 8)
g2 + geom_text_repel(aes(label=Species), segment.color=NA, box.padding = unit(-0.5, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Well it is a step forward I guess, although the labels still not plotting at the exact point positions.

Comment: Nice. So `nudge_y` pushes them all up and `point.padding` pulls them back down?

Comment: @geotheory; I'd missed the more smart method, I edited. I think so about `nudge_y`, and interpret `point.padding` is distance from the point position to the bottom of labels (if it is upperside).  But they become unnecessary...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change nudge_y and nudge_x to adjust the label.If you want to change each of points,maybe you can set up a new data frame to shore the labels' coordinate.